# Scp denied when copying files into vagrant VM

Tags: ssh, permissions, vagrant, scp

I am trying to copy a demo.zip from local host to a newly initiated vagrant VM.

I tried command like this from my MAC terminal:

```
scp -P 2200 demo.zip vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant
```

However, I get:

```
vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

And below is the log from `vagrant ssh-config`:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Volumes/dailystorage/program_analysis_VM/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

The version of vagrant box is ubuntu-xenial (Ubuntu 16.04.3).

Could anyone tell what's going on here and possible ways out?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: Solved by installing [vagrant scp](https://github.com/invernizzi/vagrant-scp).

Answer (score 0):

> The name localhost normally resolves to the IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1

So you can try copy file from your local machine to local machine.

Try this:

```
 scp -i /Volumes/dailystorage/program_analysis_VM/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key demo.zip vagrant@private_ip_address_your_remote_machine:/home/vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

I regenerated the key and it worked:

```
Generate Key Pair on master-1 node $ssh-keygen
```

Leave all settings to default.

View the generated public key ID at:

```
$cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD......8+08b vagrant@master-1
```

Move public key of master to all other VMs

```
$cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys <<EOF
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD......8+08b vagrant@master-1
EOF
```